Can I load basemap without center or set view in map initialization
I have the center coming from a different layer, however, that layer is loading slowly so initially you see a blank map container.so, I want the basemap to be visible.
view.map = L.map('map_' + mapId, {
  gestureHandling: true,
  zoom: 8,
  layers: [osm, EsriStreets, EsriImagery, EsriTopo],
  fullscreenControl: {
    pseudoFullscreen: false // if true, fullscreen to page width and height
  }
});

